# Modifying Fetched Data of all span class

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser * [Manual]](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to fetch data from websites.

Now what I wanna do is to remove first three words from all `span` which has `class="yeah"` from the fetched content. So I have implement this code but it has a problem:

```
foreach($html->find('span.yeah') as $xdat)
{
    $x_des = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', strip_tags($xdat)), 0, 3));
    $result = str_replace($x_des, ' ', $result);
    $result = str_get_html($result);
}
```

Though it delete first three words from all `<span class="yeah">` but the problem is, this modify full fetched content. But I wanna modify only those data whose are in `<span class="yeah">` but it match first three words from all fetched data and then delete all of them, though I wanna remove those data from only those span types.

**Asumming fetched data is:**

`Some first three words content <span class="yeah">first three words some content some content</span> continue to some content`

**So, the output should be:**

`Some first three words content <span class="yeah"> some content some content</span> continue to some content`

Here, **"first three words"** was the first 3 words of that span type so I need to remove it from the span type only instead of being deleted from the full content.

So, how to remove only first three words from all `<span class="yeah"> </span>` in the fetched content?

Comment: Can you post your HTML Code? Your `<span class=yeah>` isn't valid HTML code which could be part of the problem. It should be `<span class="yeah">`

Comment: ow,, sorry thats my typing mistake,, solved now :)

Comment: wat u mean by it modifies full fetched content? do u want to strip off only `span` html tags? can u show an example?

Comment: @redDevil ok, an example added..

Comment: just strip_tags enough is removing all the tags for me including `span` and the `class` attribute,
`$result =  strip_tags($xdat);`

Comment: @redDevil but it cause a `Fatal error`

Comment: can u check the answer and tell me wat error it gives u?

Comment: that is: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\UwAmp\phpapps\uwamp\prijom\v2.php on line 1480

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('span.yeah') as $xdat)
{
    $result = strip_tags($xdat);
    $result = str_get_html($result);
}
```

it will strip all the html tags and attributes though including `span` and `class="yeah"`.